# How do I change where docker-compose mounts volumes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file which I am trying to run inside of Google Cloud Container-Optimized OS (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os). Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "9876:9876"
    links:
      - api
    command: bash -c "yarn --pure-lockfile && yarn start"
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - api
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
  api:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I eventually get the error:

`Cannot start service api: error while creating mount source path '/rootfs/home/jeremy/my-repo': mkdir /rootfs: read-only file system`

Reading further, it appears that `/rootfs` is locked down (https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security), with only a few paths writeable. I'd like to mount all my volumes to one of these directories such as `/home`, any suggestions on how I can do this? Is it possible to mount all my volumes to `/home/xxxxxx` by default without having to change my docker-compose.yml file, such as passing a flag to `docker-compose up`?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. How did you get rid of the error in the end?
My docker-compose.yml file is located in _/home/myusername/_.
I have some volumes specified in my docker-compose.yml, for instance:
`./redis-data:/redis-data`

According to the [gcp-docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security), I should be able to write the _/home_ directory.
So I wonder why I still get the error: `mkdir /rootfs: read-only file system`?

Comment: @user2350644 I didn't manage to resolve the issue - I had to change my docker-compose.yml file in the end to mount it to a different path.

Comment: For me it worked in the end when I simply specified full paths for my volumes. Taking my example before, I changed the volume command to: `/home/myusername/redis-data:/redis-data`.
This way my services start up without any errors.

Comment: But you still had to modify your docker-compose.yml file right? I was trying to build without modifying that at all

Comment: Yes I had to change the docker-compose.yml file. But thats fine in my case.